# Config files transform stopped working after upgrade to .NET Framework 4.5

Tags: msbuild, configuration-files, .net-4.5, slowcheetah

After upgrading our solution to .NET Framework 4.5 the transformation of our config files stopped working.

I also asked a question that might be connected to this but still a separate question, [After upgrading solution to .NET framework 4.5 the daily deploy stopped working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12955967/after-upgrading-solution-to-net-framework-4-5-the-daily-deploy-stopped-working).

I have another way of deployment too, as below.

```
<MSBuild
                Projects="$(SolutionRoot)\My.Web\My.Web.csproj"
                Properties=
                "OutDir=$(OutDirPath)\My.WindowsService\;Configuration=Dev;DebugType=pdbonly;Optimize=true"
                ContinueOnError="False"
                />

<Exec Command="&quot;$(MsDeployExePath)&quot; -verb:sync -source:contentPath=&quot;$(OutDirPath)\My.WindowsService&quot;                 
              -dest:contentPath=&quot;E:\dev.mywindowsservice&quot;,computername=https://10.xxx.xxx.xxx:8172/MsDeploy.axd,username=UserName,password=Password,authtype=Basic -allowUntrusted=True"
              ContinueOnError="false" />
```

This has been working before the upgrade of .NET Framework and it still deploys the application to the right spot.

But, the transformation of the config files, using SlowCheetah, is not working any longer.

I have upgraded SlowCheetah assemblies as well since we are now using VS2012.

It seems like it has something to do with MSBuild just as my other case but I can't really find out what is wrong.

The transformation do work inside VS2012, both as we are building the solution and as right-click 'Preview Transform'.

Anyone have had the same problem and knows what to do?

Comment: No, I made a mistake of my own. Missed to upgrade the targets file that my TFS build was using, only upgraded the assembly.

Comment: I just answered one of your other questions LOL. I'm glad that you figured this out. BTW if you haven't purchased a copy of my MSBuild book I'm gonna stop answering :)

Comment: Well, I actually have, when working with msbuild at my former client. But at that point we were never near msdeploy so that is a new experience for me.

Comment: I have a similar problem. After setting my ASP.NET MVC project's target framework to v4.5, configuration transforms in TeamCity stopped working.